# Car DRL Led wiring beginners question

Tags: led, wiring

I bought this relay (http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/400972235163) and this LED DRL lights (http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/400757922989).

The questions are:

1. Can I attach 2 led lights to this relay (as it only has one red and one black wire) ?
2. If (1) yes, can I splice that red and black wires to get 2 red and 2 black wires?
3. If (2) yes, can I just solder and protect the ends of two red wires to the one from the relay ( a same for black ) ?
4. If (3) yes, can I use this cable (http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/321770426302) to extend everything? Relay says 12V 5A and mentioned cable says 12V 8A.

Image attached ( that's what I have in plan )... is that all right?

[image: This is what I had in plan]

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, and yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Yes, you *can* attach any number of LEDs (or pretty much anything else you like) to the relay, so long as you ensure that there is never more than 5A of current drawn through it. CAVEAT: The LED lights you linked didn't have a listed wattage or amperage. Without knowing how much power they draw, we can only guess as to whether or not the pair of them could take more than your relay's max 60W/5A.

2 & 3: Yes, and for vehicle wiring, soldering or crimp-on connectors are the preferred attachments as the vibrations can cause other connectors (like wire nuts) to work loose.

4: Yes, any wire rated for at least 5A/12V should be safe to use with that relay.

Image: Yep, that's how to do it.